# How to change Android emulator (android studio)display from portrait to landscape mode andvice versa

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I searched how to change Android Studio emulator display from portrait to landscape mode but did not find. help

Answer (score 0):

For windows: left Ctrl + F12

For mac: ctrl + fn + F11

Hope this helps